# How to make a Dialog box to insert name?

Tags: java, jframe, dialog

I am making a game and I have two labels, player 1 and player 2. Before the game begins I want a dialog box to pop-up where user can insert in the name of player 1 and player 2. Below is my code. It should change the label to the names inserted.

```
public void gui();
{

    BorderLayout borderlayout = new BorderLayout();

    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Games");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(600,400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    Panel p2 = new Panel();
    p2.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    p2.add(new Label("Player 1"), BorderLayout.WEST); //player 1 label
    p2.add(new Label("Player 2"), BorderLayout.EAST); //player 2 label
    p2.add(new Label("Board GAME"), BorderLayout.NORTH );
    p2.setBackground(new Color(156, 93, 82));
    p2.setFont(new Font("sansserif", Font.BOLD, 18));
    frame.add(p2);
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign your `JLabels` to variables first:

```
JLabel player1Lbl = new JLabel("Player 1");
p2.add(player1Lbl, BorderLayout.WEST);
```

Then get the text from the player using a JOptionPane

```
String player1Name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Player 1 enter your name");
```

Then set the label

```
player1Lbl.setText(player1Name);
```

This method does not check if the user entered anything, so the string could be blank or null, you can work out how to check for that though...

Answer (score 2):

You can easily to it with cass `JOptionPane`:

```
String p1name = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(frame,"Please enter player 1 name","Specify name",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,);
```